# Opening a SSRS report in PDF format on an image click

Tags: reporting-services, hana, ssrs-2017

I am new to SSRS and having hard time rendering a report in PDF format.

I have a master report which within has a PDF icon. My requirement is to get a report that uses the parameters from SSRS master report and open the report in PDF format in new tab.

I tried applying the below logic from a post from Stack overflow 
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?title=I%20am%20new%20to%20SSRS%20and%20having%20hard%20time%20rendering%20a%20report%20in%20PDF%20format.)
For example, to specify two parameters, “ReportMonth” and “ReportYear”, defined in a 
report, use the following URL for a native mode report server:
http://myrshost/ReportServer?/AdventureWorks 2008R2/Employee_Sales_Summary_2008R2&ReportMonth=3&ReportYear=2008

but the same did not work.

**I need to pass the parameters from master report.

I am building my report using SSDT version 2017 and using HANA as DS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use the *Action* property with the *Go to URL* action of the icon. Use an expression to build the URL:

```
=String.Format(“http://myrshost/ReportServer/?/MyReportName&ReportMonth={0}&ReportYear={1}&rs:Format=PDF", Fields!ReportMonth.Value, Fields!ReportYear.Value)
```

This will replace the placeholders `{0}` and `{1}` in the string with values from your master (current) report and pass them as parameters to the *MyReportName* report which will be rendered as PDF.

Comment: Hi Wolfgang Kais,

Thanks a lot for the help. I guess I am stuck with a part as it gives an error saying ActionInfo.Action.hyperlink expression contains colon or line terminator. Where as I see a colon only after http and no other colon or line terminator.

Kindly help.

Comment: @Priyanka2304 Please let me know your expression. Did you enter it using the expression button ("fx")?

Comment: Yes I used the fx button:

=String.Format("http://myserver/ReportServer/PL_0001_Retail_PnL/?/Slicer_Test&FISCAL_YEAR={0}&FISCAL_WEEK={1}&SITE_NAME={2}&rs:Format=PDF",Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Week.Value,Parameters!Site_Desc.Value )

Comment: I don't even see "http". What is "PL_0001_Retail_PnL"? What are the values of your parameters (Year,  Week and Site_Desc)? I guess that "Desc" stands for "description", maybe that's what contains a line break.

Comment: =String.Format("http://myhost/ReportServer/PL_0001_Retail_PnL/?/Slicer_Test&FISCAL_YEAR={0}&FISCAL_WEEK={1}&SITE_NAME={2}&rs:Format=PDF",Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Week.Value,Parameters!Site_Desc.Value )

PL_0001_Retail_PnL : Folder that contains multiple reports
Slicer_Test : Report Name

The last part i.e the Parameters are the one which I want the PDF to have the parameter input. These are the parameters from master report

**I guess I skipped http:// while editing the host name.

Comment: I have the http part in the expression but it gets hidden while pasting the same here.

Comment: The folder name has to be a part of the report path on the right side of the question mark. The left side has to be just the report server URL, Just replace `/MyReportName` in my expression by the path and name of the report, for example `/PL_0001_Retail_PnL/Slicer_Test` followed by ampersand (&) and parameter name for every parameter.

Comment: The URL did not work. It gives a report error:
The item can not be found.

Error Text message: 

The item '/PL_0001_04_Final_PDF' cannot be found. (rsItemNotFound) Get Online Help

Below is the URL that I am using:

=String.Format("http://myhost.com/ReportServer/?/PL_0001_04_Final_PDF&Year={0}&Week={1}&Site_Desc={2}&Interval={3}&Summary_Values={4}&rs:Format=PDF",Parameters!Year.Value,Parameters!Week.Value,Parameters!Site_Desc.Value,Parameters!Interval.Value,Parameters!Summary_Values.Value)

Comment: So then, what is the path and name of the report? Is it `/PL_0001_04_Final_PDF` or ist it maybe `/PL_0001_Retail_PnL/PL_0001_04_Final_PDF`? You have to use the correct path and name of the report on your report server (behind the question mark in the URL). I don't know it and I can't guess it.

Comment: when I deploy a report on Server it automatically created a folder structure with a Data Sources, Data sets and a report project folder. This report project has all my reports. The report that I need to render in PDF format has been placed with all the other reports in the report folder. In this case do we use the report folder name in the URL path? Also when the reports are there in the same report folder why does it say report item missing?

Comment: You have to specify the folder name **AND** the report Name (behind the question mark and before the first ampersand for the first parameter)) in the form `/ReportFolderName/ReportName`. Replace blank characters by a `+` (if any). To see that part of the URL, you can also manually navigate to the report in the "Report Server Portal" and look at the URL in the address line of your browser.

Comment: It finally worked. :)

Thanks a lot Wolfganag Kais :)
You have been a big big help :)

Comment: Glad to hear that. :-)